# Magento issue with dates for catalog price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

I have set up a **catalog price rule** for my webshop, with a start date and a end date. Today is 21/04/2017. can someone explain to me why this setup (screenshot) is still working? I still have discount on the webshop even the end date has already passed. I have cleaned the cached.

[image]

Comment: Make sure your cron to update catalog rules was started after midnight. You can run it manually and see if it's still active after. The function I'm talking about is catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate

Comment: You can check your server time. Is it correct? For Linux check on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458839/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-the-terminal-and-set-a-custom-command-in

Comment: Also, try to make reindex.

Comment: I've checked the server time. it is correct. I've tried cleaned cache and reindexing. I've ran the Cron job manually. All these didn't help. If I make this rule inactive, then the discount will disappear. I'm just wondering why the end date doesn't work.

Comment: +1 we see the same confirmed. We have to set startdate-1day and endday-1 day to get it to work from startdate until enddate.